# Conditional naming of POJO classes

Tags: rest, serialization, pojo, annotated-pojos

Our problem is, our service `GET /services/v1/myobject` returns object named `Xyz`. This representation is used by multiple existing clients.

The new service `GET /services/v2/myobject` needs to expose exact same object but with different name, say `XyzLmn`

Now one obvious solution would be to create two classes `Xyz` and `XyzLmn`, then copy `Xyz` into `XyzLmn` and expose `XyzLmn` in the `v2`.

What I am looking for is, how can I keep the same java pojo class `Xyz` and conditionally serialize it to either `XyzLmn` or `Xyz` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is:

1. Write a customer serializer that emits `XyzLmn`
2. Register the customer serializer conditionally

   ```
   public class XyzWrapperSerializer extends StdSerializer<Item> {

   public ItemSerializer() {
       this(null);
   }

   public ItemSerializer(Class<Item> t) {
       super(t);
   }

   @Override
   public void serialize(
     Item value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
     throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

       jgen.writeStartObject();
       jgen.writeNumberField("XyzLmn", value.id);
       jgen.writeEndObject();
   } }
   ```

   > ```
   > XyzWrapper myItem = new XyzWrapper(1, "theItem", new User(2, "theUser"));
   > ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   >
   > SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
   > module.addSerializer(XyzWrapper.class, new XyzWrapperSerializer());
   > mapper.registerModule(module);
   >
   > String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(myItem);
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

have you try to add the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on your domain object?

Comment: I am not the consumer of 'GET /services/v1/myobject` I am producer of it.

Comment: have you try using Java Generic type? such as @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class MyEntity<T> {
 private String version;
 
        private T VersionedEntity;

}